# Fixed, small vocuabulary, language independent speech (or command) recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, speech, cmusphinx

Looking for any low-computational-complexity recognition engine (and hopefully FOSS), that works well for:

1. fixed-set / small-vocabulary (upto 100 phrases)
2. language-independent
3. discontinuous speech / commands

It is fine, if the engine is:

1. speaker-dependent
2. (thus) requires a-priori training (before recognition can be performed)

By low-computational-complexity, I mean something which I can hope to run on a 450MHz ARM9 SBC with 64MB RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Texas Instruments has an open source recognition engine for embedded platforms.
Is it for small and medium vocabularies, however you might have to make the models yourself if you need to support many languages.

https://gforge.ti.com/gf/project/tiesr/

Comment: Looks promising, thanks. In the meantime, I've been reminded of PocketSphinx, which seems to work well in platforms with low resources, though I am not sure if it'd work in my environment. Would you happen to know if TIESR has any relation to CMU Sphinx (an early branch etc.) ?

Comment: I think TIESR is totally separate engine written from scratch. There is also a small standalone engine in the Android source code, its possible to extract the code and compile and run it under Windows/Linux.https://github.com/android/platform_external_srec

Comment: Thanks for the standalone engine from Android pointer ! Reading through the TIESR project forum, it appears that much of the development is now in a direction that harnesses TI DSP line, rather than generic AP functionality. People seem to be having difficulty compiling the code. Of course, this is from a quick look around -- I could be jumping to conclusions here.

Comment: Well, looks like the Android speech-recognizer is based on some Nuance IP, and more importantly, has relatively heavy processing requirement, which is why it was introduced in ICS with better hardware specs. So, usage on ARM9 seems to be pretty much a no-go.